# std::transform with virtual call operator throws "global functions do not have 'this' pointers"

Tags: c++, stl, mem-fun

PayOff is an abstract base class and CallPayOff and PutPayOff derive from it. The call operator is defined as a pure virtual function in base class and CallPayOff and PutPayoff provide their own implementations.

```
vector<PayOff*> v;
v.push_back(new CallPayOff(20));
v.push_back(new PutPayOff(20));
vector<double> payVals;
payVals.reserve(v.size());
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(payVals),  bind2nd(mem_fun(&PayOff::operator()),this));
```

Call operator is defined as:

```
class PayOff
{
public:
    virtual double operator()(double spot)const = 0;
    virtual ~PayOff(){}
};
```

Can anyone please take a look? Boost/C++11 is not an option.

Comment: Sorry, just the older version.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling transform in "main".

Comment: So there is no `this`. Presumably, you want the `transform` to call each object with some value; that value (rather than a nonsensical `this`) should be the argument to `bind2nd`.

Comment: Well, why do you want to use `this` here? That one is completely misplaced, instead you need to bind a `double` (as this is the 2nd argument of your wrapped member function).

Comment: What do you want to be executed for each element? operator() with **what** `double` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you expect the `transform` to do; presumably it's to invoke each `PayOff` object on some value. In that case the functor should be:

```
bind2nd(mem_fun(&PayOff::operator()),some_value)
```

or, for those not stuck in the past,

```
[=](PayOff* p){(*p)(some_value;}}
```

or

```
bind(&PayOff::operator(), _1, some_value);
```

You are instead trying to bind to `this` which, in a global function, doesn't exist. In a member function, it would exist, but wouldn't make sense as an argument to a functor that expects a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), payVals.begin(),  
          bind2nd(mem_fun(&PayOff::operator()),this));
```

The names in the call to `transform` must be looked up and resolved at the place where the call takes place. Which according to your comment is `main`. Inside `main`, you cannot use `this`.

If you have a C++11 compiler you can opt to either use a lambda or `std::bind`:

```
std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
               std::begin(payVals),
               [](PayOff* p) { (*p)(value); });
std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
               std::begin(payVals),
               std::bind(&Payoff::operator(), _1, value); // using std::placeholders::_1
```

In C++03 you can use `boost::bind` instead of `std::bind` or if that is not available you can create your own functor or adapter functor that will call `operator()` on the argument.

Comment: Your code will not work, `operator()` takes a `double` argument. The binding itself wasn't the problem here ...

Comment: @filmor: That was later added to the question. Fixed the code, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling transform from your main function, `this` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as you should supply a double as follows (not a pointe as suggested above):

```
const double spot(99.);
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), payVals.begin(),  bind2nd(mem_fun(&PayOff::operator()),spot));
```

PS
I have not checked your syntax but essentially this is how to do in pre-c++11 code.